# How to represent hand prefab with SteamVR using Photon (unity)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, virtual-reality, photon

I'm working on a multiplayer project in unity, and I have set up the Player prefab with final IK. I'm using SteamVr and it has its own way to represent hand and finger position. I am wondering if there is a way to synchronize it with Photon.

Comment: We did it once using our own animated hand model (from Blender) and synchronized the hand states manually like thumb up/touch/down/trigger etc

Comment: Bump..................